# Validate (Bassistance) before sending to fancybox

Tags: ajax, validation, jquery, fancybox

I'm using the bassistance validation plugin and have a small script that catches the second submit-button (called preview) and sends the data via ajax to fancybox. I'ld like to validate the forms before they are send to fancybox. At the moment they're only validatet, if I send the forms via the submit-button. I tried in various ways (e.g. I put the call for validation directly after the if and so on) but couldn't get it work. Maybe there's a way to let validate know that it should also react, when the preview-button is hit?

My Code:

```
        $(function() {
            $('#myform *').tooltip();
            $('#myform ').validate();
            });

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(':submit').click(function(){
              for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances){
                CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
                }
            var value = $(this).attr("id");
            if (value == 'preview') {
                $.fancybox.showLoading();
                $.ajax({
                    type    : "POST",
                    cache   : false,
                    url     : "../mypath/",
                    data    : $('#myform').serializeArray(),
                    success : function(data) {
                      $.fancybox(data, {
                        'minWidth': '100%',
                        'minHeight': '100%',
                            });
                      }
                    });
                    return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If i'm not wrong, the Bassistance Validator plugin relies on the fact that if you SUBMIT a form, and the requirements are not met, the function returns a "false" on that submit, enabling you to visually see the errors made.

In your source code, you correctly initialized the Bassistance validator plugin at the very beginning of your code ( I assume you created the rules for it directly on the input fields for example minlength="2" required ) but there is a problem: there is no hook for the SUBMIT event of the submit button, but only for the CLICK event on that button.

There is a simple example on the Bassistance website that shows how you can use custom submit events for the plugin:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html

Basically, what you need to do is to insert the intelligent part of your code into

```
jQuery("#yourform").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
            /*
                Here you can do the following:
                1) Update the instances of CKEDITOR
                2) Check if the submit is in the preview mode
                3) If yes
                    - do your fancy stuff
                    - return false so that the real submit is not triggered
                   If not
                    - return true so that the real submit handler is evaluated by the browser and the POST is triggered
            */

        });
    }
});
```